# numpy 3d array and 1d array addition on first axis

Tags: python, numpy

i have a 1d np array "array1d" and a 3d np array "array3d", i want to sum them so the n'th value in "array1d" will be added to each of the elements of the n'th plane in array3d.

this can be done in the following loop

```
for i, value in enumerate(array1d):
    array3d[i] += value
```

question is, how can this be done in a single numpy line?

example arrays:

```
arr1d = np.array(range(3))
>>>array([0, 1, 2])

arr3d = np.array(range(27)).reshape(3, 3, 3)
>>>array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

wanted result:

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18]],

       [[20, 21, 22],
        [23, 24, 25],
        [26, 27, 28]]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Numpy's [broadcasting features](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
In [23]: arr1d[:, None, None] + arr3d
Out[23]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18]],

       [[20, 21, 22],
        [23, 24, 25],
        [26, 27, 28]]])
```

This basically copies the content of `arr1d` across the other two dimensions (without actually copying, it just provides a view of the memory which looks like it). Instead of `None`, you can also use [`numpy.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis).

Alternatively, you can also use `reshape`:

```
In [32]: arr1d.reshape(3, 1, 1) + arr3d
Out[32]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18]],

       [[20, 21, 22],
        [23, 24, 25],
        [26, 27, 28]]])
```